# Unresolved identifier 'join' and 'array' is unavailable

Tags: swift

While I use Xcode 8.1.2 to edit the lines of code, the two problems occurred. Please help me solve the problems.

1. Use of unresolved identifier ‘join’

Xcode 8.1.2 indicates Use of unresolved identifier ‘join’
Line of Code: 6

```
    func countryFromFilename(_ filename: String) -> String {
        var name = filename.components(separatedBy: "-")[1]
        let length: Int = name.characters.count
        name = (name as NSString).substring(to: length - 4)
        let components = name.components(separatedBy: "_")
        return join(" ", components)
    }
```

2.'array' is unavailable: Please use Array initializer instead. 
   Line of code: 1

```
        if model.regions.values.array.filter({$0 == true}).count == 0 {
            model.toggleRegion(regionNames[defaultRegionIndex])
            switches[defaultRegionIndex].isOn = true
            displayErrorDialog()
```

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: For the first one, the return statement is trying to access a method `join(_:,_:)` that is not available to the scope in which it is called (this is not a known standard function).

Comment: `join` was (I think) a global function in ancient Swift versions. You want `components.joined(separator: " ")` in Swift 3.

Comment: ... and probably `Array(models.regions.values).filter(...`

Comment: ... or simply `model.regions.values.filter(...)`

Comment: ... and thereafter considering reading up on the current state of non-ancient Swift in the [Swift Langauge Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). If your full code base is ancient, you will run into alot of stuff like this when attempting to update it using modern Swift. Note also that the conditional withing the filter call, `$0 == true`, can simply be tested for `$0` (`.filter({ $0 })...`).

Answer (score 1):

*(Summarizing above comments:)* There is no global `join` function in
Swift 3. To concatenate an array of strings, use

```
components.joined(separator: " ")
```

Secondly, *"'array' is unavailable: Please use Array initializer instead"*
means that

```
model.regions.values.array
```

should be

```
Array(model.regions.values)
```

However, there is no need to create an array, you can filter the
`values` sequence directly:

```
if model.regions.values.filter({$0 == true}).count == 0
```

which in turn can be simplified to

```
if !model.regions.values.contains(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help!!!    components.joined(separator: " ") is good to work.   if !model.regions.values.contains(true) is also workable.

Comment: @MikeChen: You are welcome. – If this answer solved your problem then you can *accept* it by clicking on the check mark.